# Perl - Hyphen and Minus

Tags: perl

I have a method where i split terms bounded by white-spaces. I want to remove the minus sign when it is alone like these:

```
$word =~ s/^\-$//;
```

The problem is that i cannot visually identify the difference between a minus and a hyphen (used for separating two words for example). How can i be sure that i'm only removing the minus sign?

Comment: Well, assuming you are not trying to parse code, a minus should always have no characters before it other than whitespace, whereas a hyphen should have `\S\s*` before it.  If you post some of your sample data, we may be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to his source code, rather than to his data. @Andrew, can you clarify whether you have trouble to visually identify a minus and a hyphen in your Perl source code (in which case my answer applies), or in your data (in which case I misunderstood your question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ASCII printable character set, the hyphen and minus are the same symbol (ASCII 45), so when you're just scanning printable ASCII text data, whether you remove it or not would really depend on the context. Also, hyphenated words shouldn't contain whitespace, and when used to set apart a phrase -- like this -- you'll usually find two consecutive dashes. So if you're finding the symbol on it's own there's something unusual going on in the file.

To match the En-dash character or Em-dash characters, you'd search for \226 or \227 respectively (the ASCII value in octal).

Comment: ASCII only goes up to `\177`. U+2013 is EN DASH, U+2014 is EM DASH, U+2010  is HYPHEN, U+2011 is NON-BREAKING HYPHEN, and U+2212 is MINUS SIGN.

Comment: So would it be correct to say "To match the En-dash character or Em-dash characters, you'd search for \226 or \227 respectively (the UTF-8 value in octal)" I suppose only if you know the file you're searching is UTF-8, eh? (I'm now in over my head, BTW ;-)

Comment: No, \226 is decimal 150, which is U+0096 START OF GUARDED AREA.  \227 is decimal 151, which is U+0097 END OF GUARDED AREA.  You must be thinking in terms of some legacy encoding system, not in standard Unicode or ISO 8859-1.

Comment: To search for an en dash, you would use `/\N{EN DASH}/` after employing the `use charnames qw(:full)` pragma to your code.  And you would have to specify the encoding of the input; otherwise you cannot know what you have. Note that there is also a Dash property, `/\p{Dash}/`, which matches any characters with that property.

Comment: Yeah, turns out I was working with what's technically Windows-1252, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 ...

"It is very common to mislabel Windows-1252 text data with the charset label ISO-8859-1. Many web browsers and e-mail clients treat the MIME charset ISO-8859-1 as Windows-1252 characters in order to accommodate such mislabeling but it is not standard behaviour and care should be taken to avoid generating these characters in ISO-8859-1 labeled content. However, the draft HTML5 spec equires that documents advertised as ISO-8859-1 actually be parsed with the Windows-1252 encoding."

Comment: Unless you do some really weirdo stuff like `use encoding "cp1252", STDOUT => "utf8"`, which is fundamentally broken anyways, Perl doesn’t assume your locale encoding. Character numbers always mean Unicode code points, which is a superset of ISO-8859-1, which is a superset of ASCII. That’s why it is so important that you always specify the encoding of a text file. I’ve been bitten by this, and badly, so many times by other people’s code and Apple’s crufty MacRoman encoding, that it’s nearly brought tears to my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while( <DATA> ){

  if( m/(?<=[[:alpha:]])\-(?=[[:alpha:]])/ ){
    print "hyphen: $_";
  }elsif( m/\-/ ){
    print "minus: $_";
  }else{
    print "other: $_";
  }

}

__DATA__
this has hypenated-words.
this is a negative number: -2
some confusing-2 things
-to test it
title -- one-line description
```

Answer (score -4):

When coding, use a suitable editor. There are many of them, use Google or ask fellow developers. Here's a selection of notepads:

- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
- [Programmer's Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/)
- [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html)

These editors won't sell you a hyphen for a minus when you clearly hit the minus key on the keyboard. So in about eleven years of programming, I've never faced this problem thanks to using appropriate editing software for coding.

Comment: With the [Ted editor for Windows](http://jsimlo.sk/notepad/), if the cursor is to the left of the character, it shows you the decimal and 2 byte hex code too.